# Start long process after modal dialog popup

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a modal dialog with a cancel button only which pops up when the user clicks on a button. Aftre the modal dialog pops up, I would like to start a long process which monitors external event. If the event happens, then the dialog will be closed automatically. The user can cancel the monitoring process by clicking the cancel button.

I assigned the process start to the Shown event

```
private void ProceedForm_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    controller.StartSwiping();
}
```

The process itself is a loop

```
public void StartSwiping()
{           
    Status status;
    do
    {
        status = CallForFeedback();
    } while (status == Status.Pending);           

    form.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    form.Close();
}
```

The process starts fine, but the dialog does not pop up, so the user can non cancel the process. I also tried to assign the start to the Load event, but nothing changed.
Is there any way to Show the dialog and after that start the process?

Thanks

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker for long running tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing everything in the UI thread. You need to put you status monitoring loop in a separate thread so that the UI thread can remain responsive.

There are several ways you can do this, but one easy place to start is with the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Task` to do your `LongRunning` events:

```
CancellationTokenSource _cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
new Task(() => 
{ 
  //Do LongRunning task
}, _cancelationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```

Use the `_cancelationTokenSource` to cancel the task when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the long running code onto a background thread as you are blocking the UI thread, which is why the UI never displays.

Use a background worker class for the controller functionality http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

When the work is completed on the background worker (i.e. the event is received) then you can use the following mechanism to callback onto the UI thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx

Note: the article says you can turn off the crossthreadexception this would be considered bad practice, instead handle it the correct way using the InvokeRequired check and then invoke method on the windows form.

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested using a BackgroundWorker, or some other sort of background thread.  While in many cases this is appropriate here, there is likely an even better solution.  You're not just doing some long running task, you're waiting for something to happen.  Rather than constantly polling...whatever it is, you should be using events.  There should be an event that is triggered when you are done, and you should subscribe to that event to do whatever you need to do (i.e. close the dialog) when the correct conditions are met.

Comment: thanks, that is absolutely true, but the I can assign event handlers to BackgroundWorker class to do something when the process finished

Comment: @ZoltanHamori Depending on the implementation the event handler may be fired in a UI or non-UI thread.  Most likely it will be a non-UI thread.  If it's not the one that you want you can always get the other.  If you're in a non-UI thread you can marshal into the UI thread, and if you're in the UI thread you can start a new task to run in the background.